# Music player in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

Which is a best way to fetch the all my audio files which store in my local device storage and use in a my react native offline music player app . Or suggest me library which help me to archive this task

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The package [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player) offers a simple API for playing music and includes local media support.